# show user settings in tableview from rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to fetch some user notification settings that belong to the user Model. I'm trying to return an array that has the notification column name, a friendly name, and it's value (true/false). This is because I want to be able to dynamically show settings and I need the friendly name to show it and the column name to update it when I return the call.

I'm having issues retrieving this information in a way that allows me to do this on my IOS front end.

Right now I have this in my user model:

```
 def user_notifications
    ret = Hash.new
    ret[:notification_likes] = notification_likes
    ret[:notification_followers] = notification_followers
    ret
  end
```

And this in my controller which returns those values

```
def user_settings
    render :json => current_user.user_notifications
  end
```

I can very easily hard code some stuff into my IOS code to assume only those two notifications will come back but as I said, I want it to be dynamic. How do I include a friendly name in this result to be able to parse it in my front end (SwiftyJSON)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got this to work. Not the most scalable solution but it does the job.

Here's my code in my user model:

```
def user_notifications
    return [{"friendly_name": "Likes", "column_name": "notification_likes", "value": notification_likes},
    {"friendly_name": "Followers", "column_name": "notification_followers", "value": notification_followers}]
  end
```

This will return a dictionary of notifications like this:

```
[
  {
    "column_name" : "notification_likes",
    "value" : true,
    "friendly_name" : "Likes"
  },
  {
    "column_name" : "notification_followers",
    "value" : true,
    "friendly_name" : "Followers"
  }]
```

Then I just created a model object in my IOS app that is called UserPushNotificationSetting and I go through the results and create one and add it to an array.

The logic for the rest is as follows.. my tableview will display custom cells that have a variable of type UserPushNotificationSetting... in my CellForRow I will set to the cells UserPushNotificationSetting the one at the current index of my array.

Back in my cell, I will show the friendly name and set the value for the push notification setting. Everytime value is changed, my cell will send a call to my api with the column name and the new value... works perfectly. Probably could be better but does the job for now.